# How to properly reload a changed Eclipse plugin at a local update site

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have two instances of 2019-12 Eclipse installed and running.  One is the "Java Developer" instance that I use for normal Java development.  The other is the "RCP and RAP" instance, where I'm working on the code for an Eclipse plugin that I'm trying to use in the "Java Developer" instance.

I've installed the plugin in the JD instance with a "Local Update Site", which points to the directory containing the "Update" project for the Eclipse plugin.

When I want to test new changes in the JD instance, I go to "About" and select the two plugin entries the plugin creates, then uninstall them.  I then go to the RCP instance and open the "site.xml" and click "Synchronize" and then "Build All".  I then back to the JD instance and "Install New Software" selecting the local update site again, then let it restart.

When I test the changes, it seems like it's not getting my new changes.  If I instead test the changes by running the Debug instance from the RCP instance, I see the expected results from the new changes.

Is there an obvious problem with the steps I perform to reinstall the plugin with new changes?  I couldn't even figure out how I could inspect the files in the filesystem to see if the new changes were installed.  I don't see a jar file in either the distribution or the workspace that appears to have the plugin jars.

**Update**:

Based on the comment from @greg-449 , I tried changing the version from 4.2.0 to 4.3.0 in the manifest, feature.xml, and site.xml files, then rebuilt and uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin.  As expected, the reinstall found version 4.3.0 instead of 4.2.0.

This successfully showed the log lines.  In addition, the feature that had stopped doing anything is now working perfectly fine.

Reflecting on this, the fact that I had to fix the "javax.inject" import problem definitely implies that I should be incrementing the version number, but it still doesn't make sense to me that I had to increment the version number to get the installation to see the new code.  I had uninstalled the plugin before installing it again.  Are the plugin jars stored in a cache somewhere, such that uninstalling the plugin and then reinstalling it just used the older jars instead of the new jars, acknowledging that the version numbers were the same?

I also note that when I edit the plugin code to remove the log statements, as I don't need them anymore, without incrementing the version, and uninstall and reinstall the plugin, it still shows the log statements. It appears that I'll have to increment the version again to get it to remove the log statements.  I can see this is consistent, but it still doesn't make sense.  I uninstalled the plugin.

Comment: You probably need to change the version number of the plug-in (at least one of the first three parts). Also try starting with the '-clean' flag.

Comment: I tried starting the main instance with "-clean". Still doesn't show the logs. I started the update process by uninstalling the plugin. Are the plugin jars kept in a cache somewhere, such that the reinstall used the old jars instead, which were not removed by "-clean"?